# Is the transformation $T(x,y) = (0,xy)$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is $T(x,y) = (0,xy)$ linear transformation?

I tried first rule: $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$

$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ from $\Bbb R^2$
$$\begin{align}
T((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)) ={}& T(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\\
 ={}& (0, (x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)) \\
={}& (0, x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2) \\
={}&(0,x_1y_1) + (0, x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2) \\
= {}&T(x_1,y_1) + (0, x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2)
\end{align}$$so the first rule doesn't work and it's not linear transformation.

So, I did not check $T(ax)=aT(x)$.
Is it wrong?

Comment: No! One of the important properties wasn't held, so you're done.

Comment: Well, think about the definition. $T$ is linear if both your rules hold. The contrapositive of your statement is if at least one rule does not hold, then $T$ is not linear. Since you already showed the first rule does not hold, what do you conclude about $T$ ?

Comment: So, I showed it correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have found one requirement that fails, you are done. You do not need to check every requirement. A single failed requirement is enough (although $T(ax)=aT(x)$ might have been faster to check).

Also note that you don't need to do it in any kind of generality. You have used $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ here, but you could just as well have used $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. If a requirement that should hold for all vector pairs fails for even a single vector pair, it has still failed.

In fact, doing it generally leads you into a trap. You have shown that
$$
T((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))
= T(x_1,y_1) + (0, x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2)\\
=T(x_1,y_1)+T(x_2,y_2)+(0,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)
$$
(note that I took the liberty of finishing the calculations you had; that last line is what we are really after, as it has $T(x_1,y_1)+T(x_2,y_2)$ in it). However, we are not done.

It is theoretically possible that that extraneous term $(0,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$ that shouldn't be there is actually always $0$. In this case it turns out not to be, obviously, but there are plenty of obscure ways to write $0$. Suddenly you will find yourself with a transformation that truly is linear, but where you get a monstrous extra term that turns out to always be $0$. Or similarly for any other property you would want to check in the future.

At any rate, you *must check* that this extra term not only looks like it could be non-zero, but actually *is* non-zero, at least occasionally. Checking this by using concrete numbers to start with is the easiest in my opinion, although you may have bad luck when picking your numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You should check that $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ fails with a concrete example. For instance, $T((1,2)+(2,2))=T(3,4)=(0,12)$, but $T(1,2)+T(2,2)=(0,6)\ne(0,12)$.

But after having seen this, yes, there is nothing else to check.